# LSD-SLAM virtual camera calibration

Tags: ros, lsd-slam, ros-indigo, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have recorded some actions using  $rosbag record within the virtual simulator called UWSim. I am trying right now to make it work with lsd_slam.

My camera topic is /g500/camera1
Therefore, I ran lsd_slam as follow:

```
 rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam image:=/g500/camera1 camera_info:=/camera_info
```

Now of course I am getting a message saying "WAITING for ROS camera calibration!". I have found someone previously asking how to [calibrate virtual camera](https://answers.ros.org/question/305145/calibrating-virtual-camera/), however the answer was there is no need. Then what kind of calibration data I should send?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316452/lsd-slam-virtual-camera-calibration/) by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2019-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Managed to solve it.

I calculated the camera parameters and this is what Ive got (I calculated these by following this [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/263542/calibrating-camera-for-lsd-slam/)):

```
0.804 1.07 0 0 0
320 240
none
320 240
```

I saved these configs into a my_calib.cfg file in /lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/calib.

Then I ran the following line:

```
 rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam image:=/g500/camera1 _calib='path//lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/calib/my_calib.cfg'
```

and after that I ran

```
rosbag play *my_file*
```

LSD_SLAM reacted and showed some signs of being ALIVE!

---

Originally posted by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) with karma: 75 on 2019-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0